# Constructing a Continuous Everywhere but Nowhere Differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, continuity

In Neal Carothers' *Real Analysis* he claims that $$f(x)=\sum_{k \mathop = 0}^\infty 2^{-k}g(2^{k}x)$$ is a continuous but non-differentiable function over the real line if $g(x)$ is the distance between $x$ and the integer closest to $x$.

He then defines a dyadic rational to be a rational number of the form $\dfrac{i}{2^n}$ where $i$ is an integer, and that by two *successive* dyadic rationals he means $\dfrac{i}{2^n}$ and $\dfrac{i+1}{2^n}$. Skipping a few steps ahead to the part I don't understand, he writes the equation: $$\dfrac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}=\sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{n-1} \dfrac{g(2^{k}v_n)-g(2^{k}u_n)}{2^kv_n-2^ku_n}$$ Where $u_n$ and $v_n$ are a pair of successive dyadic rationals, and $n\ge 1$.

To me, the right hand side of the equation is the $(n-1)^{th}$ term of the sequence $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k \mathop = 0}^n 2^{-k}g(2^{k}x)$$ at $x=v_n$ minus the $(n-1)^{th}$ term of the above sequence at $x=u_n$, all divided by $v_n-u_n$. How can this be equal to the expression on the left hand side? Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know [Weierstrass' function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $k\ge n, 2^k u_n = i\cdot 2^{k-n}$ and $2^k v_n = (i+1)\cdot 2^{k-n}$ are integers, so $g(2^k u_n) = g(2^k v_n) = 0 \quad\forall\ k\ge n$, thus
$$\frac{f(u_n) - f(v_n)}{u_n - v_n} = \frac1{u_n-v_n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{g(2^k u_n) - g(2^k v_n)}{2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{g(2^k u_n) - g(2^k v_n)}{2^k u_n - 2^k v_n}$$
The series are absolutely convergent (because they are bounded by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{2^k} = 2$) so they can be combined as is done in the first step.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!